# Using sodium chloride load as a point source pollutant variable in SWAT model?

Tags: hydrology, soil, water

I'm currently working with the Soil & Water Assessment Tool (SWAT). My task is to model the loading of sodium chloride into streams.

One approach I would like to take is to use the point source rechour.dat file command. The file can contain several variables regarding pollutant load.
For example:

- `ORGPHR` is the organic P loading kg/hr,
- `NO3HR` is NO<sub>3</sub> loading kg/hr,
- `DISOXHR` is O<sub>2</sub> loading kg/hr,
- etc...

**But interestingly enough there is no NaCl loading variable!**

Am I able to customize a new variable explicitly NaCl, or will I have to use `CMTl1HR` which is a heavy metal loading kg/hr?

I was also thinking I could customize a soil type with high salinity.

To you hydrologists out there: what are my options?

Comment: You might try asking one of the SWAT user groups: http://swat.tamu.edu/support

Comment: Does the program not allow you to define arbitrary items?  Some items are messy due to interactions with life (P, NO3) Some have messy chemistry (Most transition metals have insoluble oxides or sulfides, and so are removed from flow)  But Na should be relatively inert -- solubility doesn't change much with temperature, or pH.  Note however that a lot of sodium is balanced not with chloride, but with carbonate and bi-carbonate.